# List of dalvik opcodes with operand details

Tags: dalvik, opcode

Where can I find a list of the dalvik opcodes with the corresponding *allowed* operands and their sizes (8-bit/16-bit/32-bit/62-bit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode) gives all the details of each opcode present in the dalvik vm and [this](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/instruction-formats.html) gives all the instruction formats used in the table in link 1

Comment: Those links no longer take one to information that answers this question.  Do you have updated links?

Answer (score 1):

There's a much better list here:

http://pallergabor.uw.hu/androidblog/dalvik_opcodes.html

It shows all the opcodes, the operands, and the semantics of each opcode, in more detail than is found in the official docs.